# How to extract values from Queryset Django

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

When an output is received in the below form after running the query

```
<QuerySet [<key: value object (ad5bb6b4-8035)>]>
```

I want to get `ad5bb6b4-8035` string only for further operations.

So I tried

```
course_qs =  <QuerySet [<key: value object (ad5bb6b4-8035)>]>
for course in course_qs:
    print(course)
```

which returned

```
value object (ad5bb6b4-8035)
```

How to get only ad5bb6b4-8035.?

[getting values of QuerySet in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48606087/getting-values-of-queryset-in-django)
[How to extract numerical value from Django queryset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51953683/how-to-extract-numerical-value-from-django-queryset)
[Extracting message from django queryset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20128861/extracting-message-from-django-queryset)

Comment: It's not the object.id?

Comment: You can also see all the object value under its __dict__ attribute. See if its in there

Comment: @GabrielBoehme Yes its an object id

Comment: @GabrielBoehme course.id solved the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

values() is extract key,value for the specific column from queryset it's return list of dictionaries.

```
value1 = User.objects.all().values('username')
    
    #output = <QuerySet [{'username': 'one'}, {'username': 'three'}, {'username': 'two'}]>
```

values_list() is extract only values for the specific column from queryset it's return list of tuples.

```
value2 = User.objects.all().values_list('username')

#output = <QuerySet [('one',), ('three',), ('two',)]>
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: I explained in answer check it out.